# Convergence of $a_n = 3^n - 2^{n+100}(n \in \mathbb{N})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is not for a math exercise but I came across the following sequence

$$a_n = 3^n - 2^{n+100}(n \in \mathbb{N})$$

I have  to determine if it is divergent or convergent. I use the relation criteria the radic criteria but without success. How can we do this?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: write the sequence as

$a_n = 3^n (1- 2^{100} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n)$.

(Factoring out the term of the largest order of magnitude is often a good idea when evaluating limits.)

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
a_n=3^n\left( 1- 2^{100}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\right).
$$
Can you conclude?

Comment: Exact duplicate of Pete's answer!

Comment: Yep.  Great minds...

Answer (score 1):

$a_n=3^n-2^{n+100}=3^n-2^{100}\times 2^n=2^n((\frac{3}{2})^n-2^{100})\to +\infty$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: ... which was what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $b_n= a_n/2^n$ and prove that $b_n \to \infty$. This implies that $(a_n)$ cannot be bounded and hence cannot converge.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is divergent because the sequence $c r^n$ converges when $|r|<1$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$, where $c$ is a constant.  When you factor out $3^n$, you are left with a factor of $(1-cr^n)$, which tends to $1$, while $3^n$ obviously diverges, $c$ being $2^{100}$ and $r=2/3$.

Comment: Thanks guys, a great replies